Milvus Index Check Failure: Unable to Retrieve Index Information for Multiple Segments
I've encountered an issue with Milvus where multiple segments are failing to retrieve index information.
It appears that despite the indexes being created for the collections, the system is unable to retrieve index information for several segments. This is indicated by the repeated "index not found" errors.
What I've Checked:
The collections have indexes created, and a check on the collection's index status returns true.
However, the logs still indicate issues with certain segments.
Questions:

What could be causing these specific segments to fail in retrieving
index information, despite the collection showing that indexes are
present?

What steps can I take to resolve these "index not found" errors and
ensure that all segments are correctly indexed and accessible?


Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

index build only build all the existing data in the collection.
If you keep inserting data , and don't have enough indexnode in the background, then you can found some of the segment with index.
This won't affect your availbility, but may cause search to be slow.
I would recommend you to add more indexnode, and check the indexnode see if there are some warnning/error logs.
